# Any books for representation of PDF?

Tags: reference-request, random-variables

I am looking for some books about representation theory of arbitrary PDF functions. For example, about existence of any general forms for pdf of an unknown random variable

Thank you

Comment: I don't think there is a general form that would include all pdfs. Think about it, any positive integrable function can be made into a pdf. How can you come up with a general form for such a large class of functions? Or maybe I am misunderstanding what you are asking

Comment: I don't think that you mean by "representation theory" what is typically meant by that phrase. What are you looking for? Since *any* nonnegative function which integrates to 1 is a PDF, your question seems very broad.

Comment: Basically, I am seeking for an approximation of an unknown PDF. For instance, if there are n random variables x_i  with known PDF, what's the PDF of  f(x_1,\cdots, x_n), for f is polynomial function or in other more general forms.